# Questions about the dihedral group $D_8$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, dihedral-groups

Consider the dihedral group $D_8$ of order $16$.

Consider $D_8$ with the presentation $D_8=\{r^i s^j : i=0,...,7; j=0,1; r^8=s^2=e; sr=r^7s=r^{-1}s\}$, where $\{e\}, \{rs, r^3s, r^5 s, r^7s\}$ and $\{s, r^2s , r^4s, r^6s\}$ are three of its conjugacy classes (here $r$ is a rotation and $s$ is a reflection).

1) Find the remaining conjugacy classes.

2) Find the centre and class equation for $D_8$.

3) Find the subgroups of order $4$ and explain which is normal and why.

Comment: There seem to be two completely unrelated questions here. And what have you tried? Have you found other conjugacy classes?

Comment: I found {r^4},{r,r^7},{r^3,r^5},{r^2,r^6}..then centre is { e,r^4} class equation is 16 .third part stuck

Comment: Can't get that please

Comment: You should at least name your questions informatively. Also, you can format mathematical symbols and text here with $\LaTeX$ commands.

Comment: Will try it next time thanks ..does any one have a clue about this question please

Comment: Thanks l.but the answer provided is not the same here as n =8 even not odd and the order is 16

Comment: Also here s^2=e=r^8