# Finding conjugacy classes and normal subgroups of $D_8$, the dihedral group of order $16$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

What are the conjugacy classes for the dihedral group $D_8$ of order 16?

What are its subgroups of order $4$, and which of them are normal subgroups?

---

I know that $\{e\} ,\{r^2,r^6\},\{r,r^7\},\{r^3,r^5\},\{r^4\},\{s,r^2s,r^4s,r^6s\}, 
\{rs,r^3s,r^5s,r^7s\}$ are the conjugacy classes, but I don't understand how they derived these in my book; they just mentioned it without explanation.

Comment: I bet you could *at least* do some work on this...otherwise one could suspect you want someone else to do *all* the work for you. Please do show your own work on this.

Comment: I know that {e} ,{r^2,r^6},{r,r^7},{r^3,r^5},{r^4},{so,r^s2,r^4so,r^6s},{rs,r^s3,r^5,r^6s} are conjuicy class but I don't know how to derive them as r rotation and a reflection

Comment: Why would you need to do such a thing??

Comment: I would like to try every single step as I don't understand how they derived these conjugate classes in my book they just mentioned without explanation

Comment: @M alrantisi A first possible try could be to separate elements according to their orders, as conjugate elements have the same order. This doesn't seem hard at all to do with a group of order $\;16\;$ , though it can be a little time consuming.

Comment: OK thanks but what about subgroups of order 4 I can't have any of them

Comment: @M $$D_{16}=\langle\; r,s\;:\;\;r^2=s^8=1\;,\;\;rsr=r^{7}\;\rangle$$So you can take for example$$N:=\langle\;s^2\;\rangle\;,\;\;M:=\langle\;s^6\;\rangle$$ which are two subgroups of order four. Can you find more?

Comment: It's wrong presentation here as rsr=r^7

Comment: @M Of course: that was a mistake of mine as I got confused with $\;D_{32}\;$ . It **must** be $\;7\;$ there.

Comment: So can you guide me through finding subgroups

Comment: Why not first do what I proposed in my comment above: separate *first* the elements of $\;G\;$ according to their order. It's not problem here since the only possible orders here are $\;1,2,4,8,16\;$ . The first one is trivial, and the last one is impossible as $\;G\;$ isn't even abelian, much less cyclic.

Comment: I got a normal subgroup {e,r^2,r^4,r^6}

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conjugate class in the dihedral group](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556508/conjugate-class-in-the-dihedral-group). See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1064755/questions-about-the-dihedral-group-d-8.